# Removing a character from a string in Python using strip()

Tags: python, string, strip

I have two strings.

```
dat: "13/08/08
tim: 12:05:51+22"
```

I want the " character stripped from both the strings. Here is the code I am using:

```
dat=dat.strip('"')
tim=tim.strip('"')
```

The resulting strings I get are:

```
dat: 13/08/08
tim: 12:05:51+22"
```

Why is the " character not removed from tim?

According to the documentation here (http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/string_strip.htm) it should work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [docs](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.strip), `strip([chars])`:

> Return a copy of the string with the leading and trailing characters
>   removed. The chars argument is a string specifying the set of
>   characters to be removed.

So, `"` won't be replaced from `dat: "13/08/08` and will be replaced from `tim: 12:05:51+22"` because here `"` is at the end:

```
>>> dat = 'dat: "13/08/08'
>>> tim = 'tim: 12:05:51+22"'
>>> dat.strip('"')
'dat: "13/08/08'
>>> tim.strip('"')
'tim: 12:05:51+22'
```

Use [replace()](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.replace) instead:

```
>>> dat.replace('"', '')
'dat: 13/08/08'
>>> tim.replace('"', '')
'tim: 12:05:51+22'
```

Comment: OP's result is weird.

Comment: Yes, I guess OP has just mixed up strings.

Comment: Or, OP is using `"13/08/08` as `dat` and `12:05:51+22" ` as `tim`.

Comment: I guess there may be a space at the end of `tim`.

Comment: I thought it was pretty weird myself. Anyway this replace seems to work so that's fine :) Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Seem to work here

```
>>> tim2 = "tim: 12:05:51+22\""
>>> print tim2
tim: 12:05:51+22"
>>> tim = tim2.strip('"')
>>> print tim
tim: 12:05:51+22
```